# ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH not getting set in AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am trying to set the Authentication Flows in my Cognito - User Pool - App Client to the flows below in AWS CDK.

- ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
- ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
- ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
- ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH

I can only get it to add these flows.

- ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
- ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
- ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH

I am missing ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH.

My code to create the app client is as follows.

```
    cognito.CfnUserPoolClientProps(
        user_pool_id=self.user_pool.user_pool_id,
        explicit_auth_flows=["ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH, ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH, ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH, ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH"]
    )

    self.user_pool.add_client('cognito-app-client',
                              user_pool_client_name='cognito-app-client',
                              access_token_validity=Duration.minutes(60),
                              id_token_validity=Duration.minutes(60),
                              refresh_token_validity=Duration.days(1),
                              # auth_flows=cognito.AuthFlow(user_password=True),
                              o_auth=cognito.OAuthSettings(
                                  flows=cognito.OAuthFlows(
                                      implicit_code_grant=True,

                                    )
                              ),
                              prevent_user_existence_errors=True,
                              generate_secret=True,
                              enable_token_revocation=True)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - I was clearly overcomplicating this. :-)**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_cognito/AuthFlow.html

```
self.user_pool.add_client('poc-cognito-app-client',
                              user_pool_client_name='poc-cognito-app-client',
                              access_token_validity=Duration.minutes(60),
                              id_token_validity=Duration.minutes(60),
                              refresh_token_validity=Duration.days(1),
                              auth_flows=cognito.AuthFlow(admin_user_password=True, user_srp=True, custom=True),
                              o_auth=cognito.OAuthSettings(
                                  flows=cognito.OAuthFlows(
                                      implicit_code_grant=True
                                    )
                              ),
                              # scopes=aws_cdk.aws_cognito.OAuthScope.resource_server(aws_cdk.aws_cognito.OAuthScope.OPENID, aws_cdk.aws_cognito.OAuthScope.resource_server(resource_server, nested-stack_api_read_scope))),
                              prevent_user_existence_errors=True,
                              generate_secret=True,
                              enable_token_revocation=True)
```